# After update profile activity, how to stay at the same activity and allow other activity to direct to different activity based on the data?

Tags: android

I am developing an android application and using Firebase for database. I have three activities here, profile page, home page, and 3 different determine pages. In home page, there is a "determine" button which will leads to different determine page based on the data saved in Firebase at profile page.

This is profile activity. User can insert gender, age and mode to save in Firebase.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

    mAuth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    currentUserId=mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    profileUserRef=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserId);

    //get current user
    final FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    authListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null) {
                // user auth state is changed - user is null
                // launch login activity
                startActivity(new Intent(ProfileActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };

    email=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.email);
    gender=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.gender);
    age=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
    mode=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.mode);
    btnUpdate= (Button) findViewById(R.id.update_button);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);

    if (progressBar != null) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    final List<String> categories=new ArrayList<>();
    categories.add(0,"Choose determination mode");
    categories.add("Male Mode");
    categories.add("Female Mode");
    categories.add("Robot Mode");

   final ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter;
    dataAdapter= new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, categories);
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    mode.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    mode.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long l) {
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setTextSize(18);
            ((TextView) parent.getChildAt(0)).setPadding(115,0,0,0);
            if (parent.getItemAtPosition(position).equals("Choose determination mode")) {

            }
            else {
                String item=parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"Selected: "+item, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    profileUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String myEmail=user.getEmail();
                String myGender=dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue(String.class).toString();
                String myAge=dataSnapshot.child("age").getValue(String.class).toString();
                String myMode=dataSnapshot.child("mode").getValue(String.class).toString();

                mode.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
                if (myMode.equals("Male Mode")){
                    mode.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)mode.getAdapter()).getPosition("Male Mode"));
                } else if (myMode.equals("Female Mode")){
                    mode.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)mode.getAdapter()).getPosition("Female Mode"));
                } else if (myMode.equals("Robot Mode")){
                    mode.setSelection(((ArrayAdapter)mode.getAdapter()).getPosition("Robot Mode"));
                } else {

                }
                email.setText(myEmail);
                gender.setText(myGender);
                age.setText(myAge);


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

    btnUpdate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override

        public void onClick(View v){
            ValidateAccountInfo();
        }
    });


    });



private void ValidateAccountInfo(){
    String validGender=gender.getText().toString();
    String validAge=age.getText().toString();
    String validMode=mode.getSelectedItem().toString();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(validGender)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your gender...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(validAge)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your age...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else if(TextUtils.isEmpty(validMode)){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please insert your determination mode...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    else{
        UpdateAccountInfo(validGender,validAge,validMode);
    }
}

private void UpdateAccountInfo(String validGender, String validAge, String validMode){
    HashMap userMap= new HashMap();
    userMap.put("gender",validGender);
    userMap.put("age",validAge);
    userMap.put("mode",validMode);

    profileUserRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(Task<Void> task) {
            if(task.isSuccessful()){
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Profile is updated.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(ProfileActivity.this, "Error occured while updating profile..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

}
```

This is home page. When user selected "Male Mode", it will directed to DetermineM activity. If selected "Female Mode", it will directed to DtermineF activity and so on..

```
determine.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            profileUserRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(user.getUid());
            profileUserRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                        String myMode = dataSnapshot.child("mode").getValue(String.class).toString();
                        if (myMode.equals("Male Mode")) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this, DetermineM.class));
                        } else if (myMode.equals("Female Mode")) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this, DetermineF.class));
                        } else if (myMode.equals("Robot Mode")) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this, Determine.class));
                        } else {

                        }


                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });
        }
    });
```

The problem I'm having is, if i update ANY DATA (gender/age/mode) in profile activity, it will redirect me to the determine activity (DetermineM/DetermineF/Determine) based on the mode i selected. How to make it stay at profile activity after updated the data? And also allow the home page to direct to the correct determine activity. I would like to clarify more if I did not explain my question clearly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that's not related about firebase, but more to question of Android Activity Lifecycle (https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)

> When your activity is no longer visible to the user, it has entered
>   the Stopped state, and the system invokes the onStop() callback. This
>   may occur, for example, when a newly launched activity covers the
>   entire screen. The system may also call onStop() when the activity has
>   finished running, and is about to be terminated.

Seems your case will be good for `Fragment` instead of Activity for lifecycle & state changes?

Comment: Hmm..I'll try look into Fragment too. Not sure about "When your activity is no longer visible to the user.." since i just wanna update my profile as a user but it direct to other pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (myMode.equals("Male Mode")) {
                        startActivity(new Intent(homepage.this, DetermineM.class));
                    }
```

do not call startActivity instead call your adapter or method who is responsible for updating your UI

Comment: It is actually a button that when user click, it would start a Determine/DetermineM/DetermineF activity based on the value stored in database. How to call the entiire activity?